# Appending a different dataset to ONE list every iteration

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, append

In my current code I'm iterating through 4500 cell values of a column from an excel file. In each iteration, the cell value is added between two halves of an invalid URL to form a valid URL. I can then request data from the URL for that specific cell value. How can I append the datasets for each cell value to ONE list in Python?

```py
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('allstockdata.xlsx')

look = list(data["Meals"])
for i in look:
    alist = [] #Line of Interest
    i = str(i)
    alldata = json.loads(requests.get(url1half1 + i + url1half2).text) + json.loads(requests.get(url2half1 + i + url2half2).text) #Gets data in form of single nested dictionary in list for each iteration [{}]
    alist.append(alldata) # Line of Interest

    print(alist)
```

Current Output for 2 iterations:

```py
[[{'Fruit': 'Apple', 'Protein': 'Steak', 'Vegetable': 'Cabbage' }]]
[[{'Fruit': 'Pear', 'Protein': 'Chicken', 'Vegetable': 'Spinach'}]]
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```py
[
  [{'Fruit': 'Apple', 'Protein': 'Steak', 'Vegetable': 'Cabbage' }],
  [{'Fruit': 'Pear', 'Protein': 'Chicken', 'Vegetable': 'Spinach'}],
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the `alist` outside the for-loop like below:

```py
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('allstockdata.xlsx')

look = list(data["Meals"])

alist = [] #Line of Interest
for i in look:
    i = str(i)
    alldata = json.loads(requests.get(url1half1 + i + url1half2).text) + json.loads(requests.get(url2half1 + i + url2half2).text) #Gets data in form of single nested dictionary in list for each iteration [{}]
    alist.append(alldata) # Line of Interest

print(alist)
```

Comment: I believe this is what I need but is there any explanation for Memory error for print(alist)? It occurs when I run the program

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: print(alist): MemoryError

Comment: Looks like [you reached the limit of available memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#MemoryError) for your Python script. Maybe you're using a 32-bit Python version. Try switching to 64-bit.